# How do I extract multiple MySQL columns to an environment variable in a shell script?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'd like to pull some data from a table into variables in a shell script. Right now I do something like this:

```
export NAME=`mysql -NB -e "select name from user where id = $ID"`
export AGE=`mysql -NB -e "select age from user where id = $ID"`
export LOCATION=`mysql -NB -e "select location from user where id = $ID"`
```

This works fine, but I'd love to do it all in one query, like:

```
select name, age, location from user where id = $ID
```

I tried using "read" like this:

```
mysql -NB -e "select name, age, location from user where id = $ID" | read NAME AGE LOCATION
echo $NAME
```

...but it didn't work as I expected (the "echo" line has no output). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `read` in pipe, it will create a sub-shell and sets a variable in this subshell which does not affect to parent shell (where you work).
An idea:

```
export IFS=. ; set -- $(mysql -N "select CONCAT_WS('.',name,age,location) from user where id=$ID")
NAME="$1" ; AGE="$2" ; LOCATION="$3"
```

Comment: Add `-N` to the mysql command to suppress column names and this will work better